# static files in OpenShift/Python27/Django in custom build

Tags: django, openshift-online-2

I have extensively searched for a solution to my problem; however, due to the lack of success I decided to post a question.

In short: I have created an *OpenShift* app/build based on this repo (in combination with a DIY 0.1 cartridge):

https://github.com/ehazlett/openshift-diy-py27-django

The (apparently quite common) problem I have is that I can not get access to static files working; I have tried *a lot*.

These are a few things of all I have tried so far (and I am assuming that the wsgi for this build is /app/ (?)):

- STATIC_ROOT

  - I tried to set this to pretty much all possible places in my repo while placing a *static* folder with the corresponding static files in there, e.g.

    - /static
    - /app/static
    - /app/app/static
    - etc.
- STATIC_URL

  - I kept this set to *'/static/'* as this is just the URL prefix if I'm not completely wrong
- STATICFILES_DIRS

  - set this to the absolute path on the file system, there shouldn't be much that could be wrong with that.
- .htaccess
  tried a few things with .htaccess rewrites as well but mildly in the wild as I am not perfectly sure how communication flow between Django and Apache works/how Django passes static requests on to Apache and where on the file system/in the repo Apache's root dir is (?)

I can give more info if needed but that's the essential so far.

It should be noted that this seems to be a unique case with this build as I don't have problems when i create an app based on the fully supported *Python26/Django cartridge*.

Any suggestions whatsoever would be greatly appreciated..!

Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://appsembler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/static_assets.html) "Serving Django Static Assets on OpenShift", seems to suggest a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Static files should be served directly by Apache, not by Django. The process is as follows (assuming your codebase is `/srv/code/project`):

- Place your static files in `/srv/code/project/app/static/` (where `app` is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`)
- If you need static files not related to an app (or common to many), define a directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS` (usually within your codebase, e.g. `/srv/code/project/static/`) and place the files there.
- Define a `STATIC_ROOT` outside your codebase, e.g. `/srv/www/example.com/static/`. This is going to act as a cache of all static files.
- Whenever deploying a new version of the project, run `python manage.py collectstatic`. This will go through all the static directories and copy the files to `STATIC_ROOT`.
- Configure Apache to serve all requests under `/static/` from the `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: Great, thanks for your reply; however, that's pretty much as far as I had already gotten and your last step (configuring Apache to serve from the directory I define in `STATIC_ROOT`) is where I get stuck on OpenShift as I can't find a way to configure Apache (centrally or on sub-branches of the FS through `.htaccess`). If there still is a way I'd be very curious. (++ if I were able to vote yet!)

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address OpenShift at all.